# Constrain public property to specific types in List<Type>

Tags: c#, generics, interface, types

My original question was going to be basically identical to [Constrain type to specific types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406899/constrain-type-to-specific-types).

What I am looking to accomplish is basically this.

```
public List<Type> MyPublicProperty { get; set; } where T IMyCustomInterface
```

Now reading the above question I can see it is obviously not possible.

To give you an idea of context I am building a parser that is designed to support multiple types (provided they implement a specific interface) but I make no compile type assumptions about what datatypes it might be parsing. It is simply to be provided with a list of supported types and should be able to automagically work out the rest.

So basically what I am wondering is what is the alternative (besides runtime type checking when the property is set) for such a property (if any exist)?

EDIT: The suggested solution doesn't appear to work.

I end up with code that looks like this:

```
public class CustomSerializableTypeList<T> : List<T> where T : ITcpSerializable
{

}

CustomSerializableTypeList<Type> myCustomTypes = new CustomSerializableTypeList<Type>();
```

And receive the following error:

> The type 'System.Type' cannot be used
>   as type parameter 'T' in the generic
>   type or method
>   'CustomSerializableTypeList'. There
>   is no implicit reference conversion
>   from 'System.Type' to
>   'ITcpSerializable'.

The error makes perfect sense once I look at and think about the generics implementation that has been suggested.

There must be a way around this.

Comment: what about public List<IMyCustomInterface> MyPublicProperty { get; set; }

Comment: Please note: I am not looking to provide a List OF instances that implement a specific type. I am looking to provide a List OF *Types* that implement a specific interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon you would need your own list implementation that is going to wrap a `List<Type>`.  Maybe something like this:

```
public class TypeList<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly List<Type> list = new List<Type>();

    public void Add(Type item)
    {
        if(!typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(item))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Of course you would probably want to implement `IList<Type>` and then simply delegate the methods to the `list`.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a new collection type `CustomList<T>` that derives from `List<T>` and adds the type constraint, and then use this in place of `List<Type>` in your class.

```
public class CustomList<T> : List<T> where T : ICustomInterface {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please note: I am not looking to
>   provide a List OF instances that
>   implement a specific type. I am
>   looking to provide a List OF Types
>   that implement a specific interface.

There's no quick 'n' easy way to do this. You'll have to implement your own collection class, override the add method and then check to see if the type implements your interface via reflection...

```
class myTypeCollection : List<System.Type>
{
    override void Add(Type t)
    {
        if (t.GetInterface(typeof(MyCustomInterface)) == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Type does not implement MyCustomInterface");

        base.Add(t);
    }
}
```